Looking for old movie about engine trouble on US warship
I'm trying to find the title of an American movie I watched on television back in the 1960s or early 1970s. (The movie may have been made in the 1940s or 1950s.)
I think the movie took place during World War II.
As I remember it, the plot was roughly this: The US Navy wanted to test a new type of engine on a US warship. The engine was very sophisticated and proved to be too difficult to handle for the ship's crew. The crew complained that the Navy officials had given them an engine, but not given them the experts required to operate it.
In the end the Navy officials explained that they wanted to test if they could deploy the engine on a lot of warships. There were not enough experts available for all the ships, so it was vital that ordinary crew could handle the engine.
So the test failed, and the movie ends with the ship getting an ordinary Diesel engine.
Can anybody tell me the title of this movie?

This sounds a lot like You're in the Navy Now, a comedy from 1951 with Gary Cooper.

When a new commander is assigned to a [WWII] submarine chaser with an experimental engine, he finds the entire crew has as little experience as he does. 

And in the end:

Admiral Tennant reveals to Harkness that the selection of his crew was no fluke: the Navy already knew that experts could run the system; it needed to see if novice sailors, who made up the overwhelming percentage of the wartime Navy, could quickly learn to operate it.

Here's the trailer:




You beat me to it.

@Raze Sorry, didn't mean to! ;)

Yep, that sounds like the movie I was looking for. Thank you. I'll award you the bounty as soon as the system allows me to.
